# Add tableview in AlertController dynamically in swift , how?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uialertcontroller

I need to display the items like `UITableView` in `UIAlertView`. How can I do this??
or if I am getting the question wrong , suggest me geeks?

My screen should be  like

Thanks in advance.

[image]

**edited screen **
[image]

Comment: you should create new view controller with parent view have a translucent background and a child as above, use `addchildviewcontroller` to show it

Comment: if you have any sample or link please send @PhuDuy

Comment: it is same as you create a view controller but you will show it above current view controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new `UIViewController`, and before presenting it set `modalPresentationStyle` property to be `UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext`. The `UIViewController`'s view must have set `clear color` as background color and to be overlaid by a `UIImageView` with alpha 0.5 and has gray color. This will create the semi-transparent effect, then add other UI elements you need (table view, buttons, etc).

Let's say you have `CustomViewController` for displaying the content above you described. You'll present it using the following statments:

```
let customVC = CustomViewController()
customVC.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext
presentViewController(customVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Before that, customize `CustomViewController`'s in the following way:

- `CustomViewController` view must have background color set to `clear color`
- An image view which overlays `CustomViewController` view, set it's `alpha` = 0.5, and `background` color to dark gray color.
- A content view (where you'll put table view and rest of UI components you need)

As a result you'll have this view hierarcy:

[image]

Comment: when set this view as initial viewcontroller its displaying the exact view but when i am using your above code on clicking any button its shows the black screen why??

Comment: I have edited my screen in my code. plz check there the ModalAddonVC

Comment: in viewDidLoad its called like.. NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.ShowAddOn(_:)), name: "ShowAddOn", object: nil)

Comment: i have tried by creating segue.. its working but in background we cant see the previous screen data according to the screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118306/discussion-between-pradip-kumar-and-azimov).

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you have to create another UIViewController with table view and display overlay with modalPresentationStyle as @Azimov said.

Or create UITableView outside of your UIViewController and add it as subview.

Else if you still want to add in alert view, then you can do it like below.

```
var alertView: UIAlertView!

alertView = UIAlertView(title: "", message:nil , delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle:nil )

// Here you have to draft whole code for table view
// var newTableview: UITableView!
// Then you can add it on alert view by using accessoryView

alertView.setValue(newTableview, forKey: "accessoryView")
```

Comment: hey .. if i need to use your second option, from where I can set the "forKey" as you set like "accessoryView"

Comment: Just pass your table view object name like alertView.setValue(newTableview, forKey: "accessoryView") , forKey: "accessoryView") this is fix nothing to change here.

Comment: i am getting error... Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIAlertController 0x7a39f400> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key accessoryView.'

Comment: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key accessoryView.'